# How do I prevent clang-format from removing white space in an if statement around comparison operators?

Tags: clang-format

I've tried many options but
`if (foo >= bar && (foo <= bar))`
continues to be formatted to:
`if (foo>= bar &&(foo<= bar))`

I've turned all of the SpaceXYZ options in clang-format to true or false. I am using clang-format-12.

Comment: I think the best way is to remove `...&&(...)` parenthesis or add `(...)&&...` parenthesis